# Prevent N+1 queries for collections on child classes in JPA when using single table inheritance

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I am using the Single Table inheritance strategy in Postgres in JPA. Some of my child classes have collection fields of their own, and currently when I do a get on the parent class, it fetches all the rows, then for each row where it needs to fetch the collections it does a separate query.

How do I tell JPA to do only a single joined query with the child collections so I don't face the N+1 query problem? If this was a single class I could have written a JPA query myself and did a join on the child collections, but since I am only doing a get on the parent class, I can't write a query to join on the child collections.

Answer (score 0):

Beginning from JPA 2.1 to resolve N+1 problem, you can use [entity graph and sub-graph](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs) where entity graph is a way to describe a query. It has nicely been explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qPE98hZwBXA) with coding as well.

In addition, there are also other ways to fix N+1 issue, however, the [pros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703532/why-we-need-to-use-entity-graph) of entity graph is way too much compared to other solutions.